# Can I replace "throw new Exception" with a custom popup?

Tags: c#, winforms

Can I replace "throw new Exception" with a custom popup without causing problems in the program?

I want to replace this:

`throw new Exception("I show my message.");`

with this;

`this.Alert("I show my message", FAlert.enmType.Info);`

I know it's possible, but I don't know if it will cause any problems or bugs.

Comment: An exception notifies about a critical event where the application can't continue to execute or is put into a unexpected or undefined state. You can catch an exception to handle it and manually recover the application so that it is safe to continue. Removing an exception will break the client code in that it has no longer the chance to recover the application from the error or handle the exception in general, for example log it for later bug fixing.

Comment: Assuming that throwing the custom exception is really relevant then you should keep throwing it right after you have displayed the message to the user. In case this is a caught exception you must rethrow it afterwards.

Comment: The answer to such questions is almost always "it depends (on a lot of things)". You have not nearly shown enough details for there to be a yes or no answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case of exceptions you are expecting to handle, I suggest using try/catch. Within the catch, you can write code to deal with exception. This way, you decide what happens with a prepared scenario.

However, the exceptions you are not expecting will usually be the more severe ones. You should not build logic to ignore these silently, as they can have a huge impact on stability.

Comment: Thank you, if I understand correctly, in a catch I can put "throw new Exception" or "My personal popup" is it the same thing?